# settype() converts to bool instead of string

Tags: php

In PHP, the settype() function as below should change the type of $myvar to a string however when I run it it displays as *boolean*.  But If i change `$myvar` to `$my_var` settype correctly changes type to string. Why is that so?

```
<?php
$myvar=1995;
echo "The variable is an ".gettype($myvar)."<br>";
$myvar=settype($myvar, "string");
echo "The variable is now a ".gettype($myvar);
?>
```

Thanks & Regads,
rseni.

Comment: It is `integer`, not `boolean`. And your code works correctly with any valid variable name.

Comment: lol it does exactly what you wrote. @Russell Dias why did you delete your answer? it's perfect

Comment: upvoted nikic's the correct answer because I couldn't upvote Russell's deleted answer

Answer (score 6):

According to the documentation of [`settype`](https://www.php.net/settype) it changes the variable passed by reference and **returns a bool**.

Thus `$myvar=settype($myvar, "string");` first changes `$myvar` to a string and then assigns the returned bool. The correct version is:

```
settype($myvar, "string");
```